# How would I or who/what could help me find the trajectory of an "Extended Grand Tour" spacecraft, without having to take a long course on the subject?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, voyager, gravity-assist, software

(As forewarning, the most integral details of this question are **bolded.**)

For context, I have been writing an alternate history involving the accelerated development of spaceflight technology for over 5 years now (one with quite different assumptions from other examples of the subgenre), and one of its long-standing elements has been a wildly-ambitious space probe that would be sent on a Solar System Circumnavigation through a Grander Tour.

**What does this mean? Well, here are the mission objectives:**

1. **The main spacecraft body (which I will obfuscatorily name “the Spacecraft”) must fly by** ***every*** **planet (1930–2006) in the Solar System save Pluto.**
2. **At least a subprobe (“Subprobe A”) must fly by Pluto.**

   1. Double points if it manages to do so while flying by all 8 other planets.
3. **A sample, no matter how miniscule (probably micrometeorites or ring particles),** ***must*** **be returned to Earth by a subprobe or sub-subprobe (“Subprobe B”) after flying by all 8 2006– planets.**

   1. **The course correction to do so may involve as much as an orbital-scale (~9000 m/s) multi-stage solid rocket together with aerobreaking and/or a brutal gravity assist.**
   2. Double points if it is on or launched from Subprobe A.
   3. Triple points if it is on or launched from Subprobe A after the Pluto flyby.
4. **Each flyby in the Outer Solar System should preferably be at least 1 synodic period before that of the real-life Grand Tour users the Voyagers in order to prepare for the arrival of a vaguely equivalent program.**

The base of the spacecraft’s conception was that it would be launched around the time of or before the first outer planets and interstellar probes in real life (Pioneer 10/11) to make time for it to engage on a more proper Grand Tour trajectory. This was reinforced by the fact that said time range roughly overlaps with the 450th anniversary of an Earth circumnavigation expedition done by the crew of a certain navigator, who happens to be the namesake of a far less impressive real-life space mission.

**So, the rock-hard minimum and maximum are** the 450th anniversary of the start of that navigator’s voyage (**September 20th, 1969**) **and** the launch of the latter Pioneer, Pioneer 11 (**April 5th, 1973**)**. However, it would ideally be launched before September 6th, 1972,** exactly 450 years after what was left of that expedition returned, **yet as close to that date as possible (i.e. within 1972)** to allow as much advanced technology to be used in it as possible—the spacecraft would include developments like 8-bit microprocessors, helical-scan tape data storage, robotic arms, synthetic aperture RADAR, and possibly non-solid-state radioisotope generators. And yes, the first asking of this question was deliberately timed to match with the 50th anniversary of that date and the 45th anniversary of the launch of Voyager 1. (I’d have preferred it to be earlier, but ehh…)

Also, the spacecraft’s original conception had it launched on a Saturn IB–Agena D (what I thought was the highest-capacity high-velocity non-Saturn V notional “drop-in” vehicle that could have been made at the time… ignoring that either a Saturn IB–Centaur or earlier Titan IIIE would have greater capacity and could probably be made with similar R&D), but as its size and capabilities grew, its proposed launch vehicle was progressively upgraded until it became the “Saturn 1E-SB”, which consists of 4 stages (more details on which could be provided if required), the last one, not considered integral to the launch vehicle’s identity, being the main course correction stage of the spacecraft.

The first 3 stages would have the capability to put the 4th stage and ~5.5-ton spacecraft complex—~28.5 tons in total and ~6.75 tons dry mass—**on a trans-Cytherean or potentially trans-Martian injection (up to** 3650 m/s tested in KSP RSS RO using a penultimate version of the launch vehicle, **probably ~3800 m/s), beginning its Grander Tour…** A Saturn V could do so, too, and to be honest I now find justifying the existence of the Saturn 1E-SB somewhat difficult, so I may bite the bullet of switching away from a “Saturn one” platform.

**Now, how much ∆v would the course correction stage be capable of supplying?** A measly… **~5500 m/s.** And that’s **with the subprobes still attached.** So there is a very beefy, though not unlimited course-correction capacity.

Now, orbital mechanics is a complex business, and I don’t know if it would even be possible to fulfill even the barest mission requirements given the ∆v budget within that launch window, let alone how it would be done. However, the existence of trajectory designs like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BDxZV7UD9I), a flyby of all 2006– planets launched in the same vague timeframe with a negligible course-correction budget, indicates its likely possibility. **Note that the 5500 m/s and 5.5 tons payload is a maximum and minimum, respectively—the more optimized the trajectory can be made, the smaller the fuel mass of the course correction stage needs to be, allowing a greater scientific payload, so the more optimized the mission is, the better.**

And so, the question. Ideally, I’d like to have the specifics of this drilled down by April 5th, 2023 for some sense of timeliness. For more context, **this is the encounter order as planned when the conception of this mission reached its modern form:**

**Main spacecraft: Earth→Venus→Mercury→Venus→Mars→Jupiter→Saturn→Ouranos→Neptune→Interstellar**

**Subprobe A: 〃→〃→〃→〃→〃→〃→Pluto→Interstellar**

**Subprobe B: 〃→〃→〃→〃→〃→〃→〃→Ouranos→Neptune→Earth**

Comment: Theoretically, the trajectory after the Neptune flyby could be altered via a course correction so that it intercepts Pluto after an orbit (over 200 years, sadly). Unfortunately, an RTLS by Subprobe B would be near-impossible because of the hyperbolic excess velocity provided after the JSU flybys, and Neptune can only slow the craft down by so much. But maybe an aerogravity maneuver could be used to slow the subprobe enough so that it escapes Neptune at a near-zero velocity relative to the Sun. Then all it needs is a few course corrections and it will be on for a spicy reentry back home.

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide launch vehicle / transfer stage vehicle stats? Also let me know if you have access to some sort of nuclear engine which may boost mass ratio.

Comment: 1 hour of killing my CPU with KSPTOT later reports inconclusive results. I definitely think it's possible, but unfortunately I don't have the time to go number crunching right now.